Read source of specific SDK class in Android Studio
I have an exception in some SDK class (com.google.wear.services.watchfaces.FavoriteOperationException) and I want to know more about it by reading source. But I can't click on class in logcat.
How can I read the source code if I only have the class name and it is not clickable?
Double Shift search yielded no results.


Most of the com.google classes are proprietary, and for those the source is not available outside of Google.

@CommonsWare Nice. Could you give me a hintt on how I can find what went wrong? Google didn't find anything

Sorry, but by "the source is not available outside of Google", I mean that it is only available to Google employees and select others. It is not publicly available for you or I to view.

You are in an IDE: Just copy and paste the class name into the source code, make it a variable and then click on the type. If the source code is not available Android Studio will use decompiler to generate Java source code.
